# Array List in C# without a loop

Tags: c#-4.0

I like to know how to initialise the array without the loops like for, foreach or any LINQ.

From the following code, need to find under 2m length cars within .Netframework using console application.

```
{
    ArrayList = CarType new ArrayList();

    CarType.Add(new CarList("Ford"));
    ((CarList)CarType[0]).Cars.Add(new Car("Focus", 2));
    ((CarList)CarType[0]).Cars.Add(new Car("Fiesta", 1));

    CarType.Add(new CarList("Peugeout"));
    ((CarList)CarType[1]).Cars.Add(new Car("206", 1));
    ((CarList)CarType[1]).Cars.Add(new Car("407", 2));

    RemoveLargeCars(CarType);
}


public static ArrayList RemoveLargeCars (ArrayList CarType)
{
    //Array List should be here
    return CarType;

}
```

It has got two classes as follows.

```
class Car
{
    public string name;
    public float length;

    public Car(string newName, float newLength)
    {
        this.name = newName;
        this.length = newLength;
    }
}

Class CarList
{
    public string CarType;
    public ArrayList Pipes;

    public CarList(string newCarType)
    {
        carType = newCarType;
        Cars = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Can you please let me know how to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand what is your exact problem.

Comment: I need to find the cars which are only under 2m in length without using any loop and only within the RemoveLargeCars method

Answer (score 0):

Use the static `Adapter` method on `ArrayList`

```
CarType = ArrayList.Adapter(CarList);
```

But that probably uses a loop internally, you can't get away from them, but at least this hides them.

Comment: How to use the loop internally?

Comment: I mean hidden within the adapter method there is probably a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you should use the generic list type `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`, that will make the code simpler. (And best practive recommends properties rather than public fields):

```
class Car {

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public float Length { get; set; }

  public Car(string newName, float newLength) {
    Name = newName;
    Length = newLength;
  }

}

class CarList {

  public string CarType { get; set; }
  public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

  public CarList(string newCarType, List<Car> newCars) {
    CarType = newCarType;
    Cars = newCars;
  }

  public CarList(string newCarType) : this(newCarType, new List<Car>()) {}

}
```

Now use a `List<CarList>`:

```
List<CarList> CarType = new List<CarList>();

CarList ford = new CarList("Ford");
CarType.Add(ford);
ford.Cars.Add(new Car("Focus", 2));
ford.Cars.Add(new Car("Fiesta", 1));

CarList peugeot = new CarList("Peugeout");
CarType.Add(peugeot);
peugeot.Cars.Add(new Car("206", 1));
peugeot.Cars.Add(new Car("407", 2));

List<CarList> smallCars = RemoveLargeCars(CarType);
```

You can use extension methods to easily filter out cars based on a condition:

```
public static List<CarList> RemoveLargeCars(List<CarList> CarType) {
  return CarType.Select(
    t => new CarList(t.CarType, t.Cars.Where(c => c.Length < 2f).ToList() 
  ) .ToList();
}
```

Note that the method doesn't change the original list, but creates a new list.